# Python: How would it be possible to have the value of a variable instead of its address

Tags: python

I am a new user in Python and I am trying to figure out why Python provides just an adddress of the result. Why? Here below you can find the code. I would be really greatful if someone could help in order to understand how Python works.
Further explanations come below.

```
def Add(self,f=10,  type=' ', process=' '):
    if type=='A':
        self.Add = 100*f           
    elif type=='B' and process=='hot':
        self.Add = 150*f
    elif type=='B' and process =='cool':
        self.Add = 2000*f

type='B';       
process='cool';
print('Add value is:', Add)
```

In this case I get an address printed on the screen

```
Add value is: <function Add at 0x000002B42D30C400>
```

How would it be possible to have the value Add instead of its address?
Best regards

Comment: What do you expect the output to be?

Comment: It's a little unclear to me what you are trying to do. Is `Add` member function on a class? I am trying to understand why you have `self` as a parameter to `Add`. If it is a member of a class can you show the entire class? You may also want to add the expected output to your question. Finally, as mentioned below. `Add` is a function so `print(Add)` is going to return the representation of the function. If you want the result of the function you need to call the function with parameters.

Comment: Did you try *introspection*? Please edit into your question: What `value` do you hope for, how does, e.g. `print(Add.__doc__)` fall short?

Comment: Is `Add` a function or an instance method in a class? Can you demonstrate a [mcve] so we can be clear what you are trying to do? The use of `self` indicates `Add` is an instance method of a class but then `print(..., Add)` *should not work at all* then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't posted a desired output, This should get you in some light:

```
def Addition(self, f=10,  type=' ', process=' '):
    if type=='A':
        self.Add = 100*f
    elif type=='B' and process=='hot':
        self.Add = 150*f
    elif type=='B' and process =='cool':
        self.Add = 2000*f
    return self


type='B'
process='cool'
print('Add value is:', Addition(type, process))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Add value is: B
```

EDIT:

Continuing from the comments from OP:

```
def Addition(self, process, f=10):
    if type =='A':
        return 100*f
    elif type=='B' and process=='hot':
        return 150*f
    elif type=='B' and process == 'cool':
        return 2000*f


type='B'
process='cool'
print('Add value is:', Addition(type, process))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
Add value is: 20000
```

Comment: Hi, I would ecxpect that the function would return the values Add = 2000* f for instance, not B

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `'Add'` is the name of the function. So, when you try to print it, it prints the address of the function.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call Add(...)

```
print('Add value is:', Add(add_arguments_goes_here))
```

Comment: Hi Balderman, thanks for the advice. I did in the following way: print('Add value is:', Add('A','hot')) and I got None, why?